# Get a list of search results in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, full-text-search

Does anyone know of a way to get an entire list of search results in Visual Studio, or an extension that can do the same?  Normally, when using the search box, the next found item is highlighted as you go, which is nice, but sometimes it would be more useful to see an entire list of results, similar what you would get in Bing or Google.  I know that there is 'Find Symbol' but that doesn't seem to account for things you would find in comments, etc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use 'Find in Files' (ctrl+shift+f) instead of 'Find' (ctrl+f)

edit:
As Jay mentions in comments, you can also get there via the 'Find' dialog if you change 'Quick Find' to 'Find in Files' using the selector in the upper left corner of the dialog.

Comment: Same is also available from the pull-down button at the top of the Ctrl+F Find and Replace dialog. Same dialog -- different search modes.

Comment: OK, this pretty much does it.  Excellent.

Comment: I was searching that since long time. Suprising that there is no lists like in eclipse...