# Find Results not displaying Results

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Today my Find Results feature of Visual Studio 2012 stopped working. The Find Results windows displays summary information, but not the actual lines matched. This is all my Find Results window displays:

```
Find all "mytext", Subfolders, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, ""
  Matching lines: 40    Matching files: 10    Total files searched: 1129
```

I have tried all of the fixes this Microsoft forums poster has tried:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/1a02f076-29f7-46d1-879a-f8ae6d6abe95

His solution was to **reformat and re-install**.  The Microsoft MSDN Forum Assistant's answer is awesome:

> "Glad to know that you will not not be botherd by this weird problem
>   ."

Has anyone found an actual solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you please select Max's response as the answer for this? Looks like it is working out great for everyone.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Check registry fixes in this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/40c9ad4a-8cee-4f3f-b420-c7cc0463942a/). That helped me.

To make sure it won't disappear I'm copying the solution from **Martin Rosselle** here:

Please check if the following registry key is ok.  Fixing this solved the issue for me.

- Copy the text below and save it as .reg file.
- Go to regedit.exe and import saved .reg file **or** simply open the
  file with Registry Editor and click yes when prompted to continue.

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{73B7DC00-F498-4ABD-AB79-D07AFD52F395}]
@="PSFactoryBuffer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{73B7DC00-F498-4ABD-AB79-D07AFD52F395}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\MSEnv\\TextMgrP.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me: specifically, the Path was missing in the second reg entry.  As soon as I put it in, it started working without even restarting VS.

Comment: The same for me (windows 8, VS 2012). `textMgrP.dll` missing in the default value.

Comment: Perfect. Changed value of registery HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{73B7DC00-F498-4ABD-AB79-D07AFD52F395}\InProcServer32 from empty to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\TextMgrP.dll

Comment: Fixed. Still I wonder how come it worked and then it stopped... Extension?

Comment: I had to restart VS, but this solution worked. The default key (path to dll) was completely missing.

Comment: Worked for me, no restart of VS (windows 8, VS 2012 ult)

Comment: Works on VS2013 Ult as well

Comment: This started for me after installing the ResourceManager extension

Comment: This worked for me also running Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013. Important to note that this only worked with the double back slashes in the second registry key.

Comment: It works! in my case the default value of [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{73B7DC00-F498-4ABD-AB79-D07AFD52F395}\InProcServer32] was empty

Comment: Solved my 'not showing results' find in files. The default value (the path) was missing.  TNX!

Comment: It worked. verified. Just copy the text and save as a reg file and run it.

Comment: I had the same issue with VS 2013.4 on Windows 7 and this fixed it.  Awesome!

Comment: VS 2015 Community here, fixed only by changing the second register entry. Started working right away :)

Comment: I suspect this broke on my PC after installing Delphi 2009. I thought it only changed PATH environment variable, but clear it broke more than I expected.

Comment: Woah, that is random. This fixed it for me as well. I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. Earlier this week I installed Visual C++ 2008 whilst blindly following a tutorial during my attempt at compiling a certain PHP extension on Windows. I wouldn't be surprised if that somehow managed to break this registry key. (The path to 'TextMgrP.dll' was missing; it was blank)

Comment: Can confirm a fix on VS2015 Enterprise.

Comment: FYI, the only thing I changed prior to search not working was attempting an install of a Windows SDK (to get an MSI debugging tool).  It failed, I rolled it back, and apparently it trashed this registry setting.  This fix worked great, though.

Comment: Did not work for me with VS Community 2015. I ended up expanding the "Result options" portion of "find in files" when searching and chose to send the results to "Find results 2 window", which does still show up for me properly.

Comment: re-registering TextMgrP.dll with regsvr32.exe worked for me (make sure you are running the command prompt with admin rights) . Easier then creating a reg file.

Comment: om471987 and the solution provided corrected the issue.

Comment: Fixed Visual Studio 2015 - Professional. Thanks!

Comment: (sad face) this didn't work for me in VS2017.  Looks like I will be running a repair over the weekend.

Comment: This just worked in March 2021 on Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.6)... So thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve this by running:

```
Devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

from the visual studio command prompt, then running a repair on my visual studio installation.

Still a lengthy fix for such a simple problem, but not quite a reformat.

Comment: Have the same problem, unfortunately ResetSettings did not correct it.

Comment: In my case, it made things worse. The error window started to pop up on find all.

Comment: Not a best solution. You'd lose all your VS preferences!

Answer (score 2):

This issue was resolved for me after I restarted Visual Studio (2013 in my case). So make sure you try that before you dig into any of the more complicated solutions.

Answer (score 2):

See here: [Visual studio search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343956/get-a-list-of-search-results-in-visual-studio)
turned out to be a simple shortcut issue, Cntrl+Shift+F instead of Cntrl+F

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, I can resolve this issue by removing *\.*'; from the file types input

"Find and Replace" window (Ctrl+Shift+F)

[image: Ctrl+Shift+F]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in VS that has been around since 2005. Click on the 'find results' box and click ctrl+break a few times.

If that doesn't work for you, there are a few other key combinations that should - take a look here:

[No search results in visual studio](http://www.andrewdenhertog.com/tips/solved-visual-studio-no-search-results/)

Comment: This is the solution to a different symptom and does not work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to correct this issue by repairing my Visual Studio installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost similar problem where the find results window stopped showing the matching lines in code. It did show the files however. The solution was unchecking the "Display file names only" checkbox in the "Find and Replace" window (Ctrl+Shift+F), which I had checked accidentally.